# Monoid homomorphism and isomorphism

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monoids, isomorphism, homomorphism

I am reading the book 'Programming in Scala' (The red book).

In the chapter about Monoids, I understand what a Monoid homomorphism is, for example: The String Monoid `M` with concatenation and `length` function `f` preserves the monoid structure, and hence are homomorphic.

```
M.op(f(x), f(y)) == M.op(f(x) + f(y))
// "Lorem".length + "ipsum".length == ("Lorem" + "ipsum").length
```

Quoting the book (From memory, so correct me if I am wrong:

> When this happens in both directions, it is named Monoid isomorphisim, that means that for monoids `M, N`, and functions `f, g`, `f andThen g` and `g andThen f` are the `identity` function. For example the `String` Monoid and `List[Char]` Monoid with concatenation are isomorphic.

But I can't see an actual example for seeing this, I can only think of `f` as the `length` function, but what happens with `g`?

Note: I have seen this question: [What are isomorphism and homomorphisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266219/what-are-isomorphism-and-homomorphisms).

Comment: Have you seen this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993254/what-is-monoid-homomorphism-exactly

Comment: Aha!, not the selected answer, but this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993551/1612432, in **Monoid isomorphism** was the answer for me. So, in this case, `f` and `g` will be `toVector` and `toList`, right?

Comment: Oh, that one was mine, thanks! :) Yes, that's right.

Comment: @slouc I upvoted you there ;-)

Comment: Thanks :) It's nice to see that your answer helps people. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see the isomorphism between `String` and `List[Char]` we have `toList: String -> List[Char]` and `mkString: List[Char] -> String`.

`length` is a homomorphism from the String monoid to the monoid of natural numbers with addition.

A couple of examples of endo-homomorphism of the String monoid are `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase`.

For lists, we have a lot of homomorphisms, many of which are just versions of `fold`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is siyopao's answer expressed as ScalaCheck program

```
object IsomorphismSpecification extends Properties("f and g") {
  val f: String => List[Char] = _.toList
  val g: List[Char] => String = _.mkString

  property("isomorphism") = forAll { (a: String, b: List[Char]) =>
    (f andThen g)(a) == a && (g andThen f)(b) == b
  }
}
```

which outputs

```
+ f and g.isomorphism: OK, passed 100 tests.
```